# nvd3 line chart with more data on x axis than on y axis

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I have the following use case on an nvd3 line chart:

- x axis shows the entire month
- y axis shows the weight (there are no entries for each day of the month)

For the dates without weight measurement, I've set the y coordinate to `null`. Works fine, but I'm wondering if there's a way to format it differently.
Currently it looks like this:

[image]

My question is: is it possible to have the line connected from the first data point to the last one (in this example, the first one is Jul 5, last is Jul 17) to look like this (red line would be the same color as the yellow line, this is just for annotation):

[image]

Comment: What if you put `0` instead of `null` for the dates without weight measurement?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't give me the desired result as it makes the line descent to 0 which is incorrect.

Comment: You could modify the data to inject points linking the null point to the next point

Comment: @jeznag that is a possible solution I was thinking about, but I'm trying to find a way to keep the original data intact. It's not just weight, there are other charts which I need to work on with more precise and sensitive information so I cannot  inject data points and corrupt the data.